# What does [count]v and [count]V do? How is it useful?

Tags: visual-mode, visual-block, count

I am confused about how the start visual commands work when you pass them a count. I checked the help page but I am still confused.

```
[count]V                Start Visual mode linewise.
                        With [count] select the same number of lines as used
                        for the last Visual operation, but at the current
                        cursor position, multiplied by [count].  When there
                        was no previous Visual operation [count] lines are
                        selected.
```

I want to know what `[count]v`, `[count]V` and `[count]CTRL-V` does and when it is useful to pass `[count]` to the *start visual selection* commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see what it does for yourself by *performing an operation* on a 1 character selection.

```
vy3v<esc>5v
```

In that command, you select 1 character and yanked it.  Typing `3v` causes the 3 characters starting from the cursor to be selected.  Typing `<esc>5v` causes the 5 characters starting from the cursor to be selected.  This visual selection operates per-character.

```
<c-v>y3v<esc>5v
```

This one will help if you have a large block of text.  This works just like the previous one, but in visual-block mode.  You started by yanking a 1x1 grid of characters, then typed `3v` which selected a 3x3 grid of characters (starting from the cursor), and then selected a 5x5 grid.

Explaining the line-wise `[count]V` would be repetitive at this point.  However, using `[count]v` where the last operation involved *multiple lines* works a little bit differently than the first example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
```

Starting from 1,1, typing `vjey` will yank from 1,1 to 2,10. Typing `w2v` afterwards will select from 1,1 to 4,10.  Instead of selecting 2x the characters, it's 2x *lines* except the last line will always end on the same column regardless of the starting line's column.

> when it is useful to pass [count] to the start visual selection commands.

I never needed to use a `[count]v` in the past, but I imagine it has its uses when dealing with symmetrical text or in macros/scripting.  `[count]V` and `[count]<c-v>` seem to be the most useful from a user perspective, though.

There is a unit test for this feature in [test94.in](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/869e35270ecffd9024958880cb03f6f0bb01ea93/src/testdir/test94.in), but the tests don't look like something I would consider to be practical for daily use.

If you find a useful workflow using `[count]v` be sure to share it